# Why failed command in bash loop returns zero as the exit code

Tags: bash, shell

When I run a failed command, it returns 1 as the exit code.

```
> a=$(mysql -h localhost | grep local)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
> echo $?
1
```

But when I put in the loop it returns zero:

```
> for i in $(mysql -h localhost | grep local); do echo 'hi'; done
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
> echo $?
0
```

What's the reason and the best solution instead of separating the command from loop.

**Note**: the command `mysql` is just a sample to show the problem. The real command is something else.

Comment: `$?` contains return code of last command, here `yes`.

Comment: @Cyrus but it didn't being executed.

Comment: @Cyrus btw I just changed it to `echo`.

Comment: I assume that it (`yes`) will be executed once.

Comment: @Cyrus no it didn't. If it could be executed once, then it should be able to print the output.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Then the loop distorts the return value.

Comment: I think the reason the exit code 0 for the `for i in $(mysql -h localhost | grep local); do echo 'hi'; done` is because it is the exit code of the statement `for` which is working as expected. The `for` statement simply perform 0 iteration as the `$(mysql -h localhost | grep local)` return an empty string

Comment: @user696969 thanks. so how to fix it without separating the command from loop?

Comment: From the [bash manual for the `for` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#Looping-Constructs): "If there are no items in the expansion of *words* [in this case, the `$( )` -GD], no commands are executed, and the return status is zero."

Comment: @mortymacs It should work that way, right? Since when `$(..)` command get non-0 exit code, it shouldn't be performing any iteration. Or do you want it to print out a custom error message or hide the error message?

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
for i in ""$(foobar); do r=$?; [[ $r -ne 0 ]] && break; echo 123; done; echo $r
```

Output:

```
foobar: command not found
127
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really just trying to read stderr as stdout (so that loop will be executed), you can port stderr to stdout like:

```
for i in $(ls nothing 2>&1); do echo $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

As the command fails, the substitution evaluates to an empty expression, which enables the `for` loop to complete successfully without having performed any iterations. Although `for` isn't a command, but rather a control structure built-in to the language itself, `bash` chooses to define as a convention the exit code of a `for` loop to be 0 in the absence of any values over which to iterate provided that flow control was not otherwise prevented from being evaluated fully.

The error is arising within the pipeline, which is being run inside a command substitution.  In the example below, I've used a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop because the condition is evaluated in the same subshell as the control structure is operating, the entirety of which I moved to a separate subshell for which I dictated the exit code accordingly, and thus the exit code for the entire block.

```
( while read ||
        exit 1;
  do
      printf %s\\n "$REPLY"
  done
) < <( mysql -h localhost |
       grep local )
```